# Java Date Conversion with Timezone

Tags: java

I have user input date with TimeZone "GMT +5:30". But JVM is using "GMT +0:00". I want to convert Date from "GMT +5:30" to "GMT +0:00".

Thanks

Comment: A Java `Date` doesn't have a timezone.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: From Screen we are getting Date through DatePicker so We get it in "GMT +5:30" then we will convert it as it is to Date. So I need it irrespective of timezone

Comment: So you have it as a `String` initially?  If that's the case, you need to parse it using a `SimpleDateFormat`.  You can create a `SimpleDateFormat`, call `setTimeZone` and then call `parse`.  Is that what you have in mind or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

Date in Java dont have a timezone. You need to try like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5.30"));
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

Also you can use the **[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)**

Comment: This will not satisfy the purpose!